# Override `content-for` hook for installed ember-cli addon

Tags: ember-cli

I've installed the [`ember-marked`](https://github.com/huafu/ember-marked) addon. It adds content to my application via the `content-for` hook. Specifically in the header, but I don't think that matters.

I do not want the scripts or css it is injecting.

How can I override the `content-for` for an addon?